# Pad function in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using np.pad to pad 4d array

```
a = np.zeros((2,2,2,2))
a = a+7
apad = np.pad(a,((0,0),(0,0),(1,1),(1,1)),'constant')
```

It pads each 2d array with row and column of zeros.I'm not sure how this np.pad works especially the second parameter of the function.I also tried understanding it with simpler array this too is not clear.

```
a = np.arange(20)
a = np.reshape(a,(4,5))
a = np.pad(a,((1,0)),'constant')
print(a)

>>>[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
    [ 0  0  1  2  3  4]
    [ 0  5  6  7  8  9]
    [ 0 10 11 12 13 14]
    [ 0 15 16 17 18 19]]
```

Can anyone explain briefly how the second parameter works in np.pad()?

Comment: Have you seen the docs? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Comment: The second parameter tells how much the padding value will be padded in each axis. Since you specified `((1, 0))` then each axis will get padded once at the beginning and 0 times at the end. Try `np.pad(a,((1, 0), (0, 1)),'constant')` I think that will help clarify this.

Comment: With a 2d array, there are 4 sides that can be padded .  Look for example at `np.pad(np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2), ((1,2),(3,4)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from your second example (a **2-D** array).

When you run `np.pad(a, (1,0), 'constant')` then *(1,0)* means:

- add *1* element before,
- add *0* elements after,
- since you put only one *(before, after)* pair, it pertains to
  each dimension.

The result is that:

- 1 **row** was added before the array, and nothing after (for the first dimension),
- 1 **column** was added before the array, and nothing after (for the second dimension),
- added elements are by default *0*,

and hence the result is:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 0, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

​And now look at your first example. Let's create your array also of *int* type:

```
a = np.zeros((2,2,2,2), dtype=int)
a = a + 7
```

Then, whe you run `apad = np.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,0),(1,1),(1,1)), 'constant')` then:

- nothing was added in the first and second dimension (first 2 pairs
  of *(0,0)*),
- in the third and fourth dimension 1 element was added, both before and
  after (2 following pairs of *(1,1)*).

So the result is:

```
array([[[[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]],


       [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 7, 7, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]]])
```

Comment: Great explanation , now I can understand how this works. Thanks a lot!